# How to add constraints with a large amount of objects in SQL query?

Tags: sql, filter, mysql-workbench, where-clause, workbench

I want to get output from a SQL query by adding

```
WHERE ID IN (
15325335122,
85962128962,
12354789522,
64125335125,
64523578945,
12354784589,
......
........)
```

This list contains over 9000 rows, I'm wondering if there's an easy way to add them in the where statement since I don't want to copy and paste and add comma one by one. I'm new to SQL, can someone help me? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured out the solution by following [this instruction](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UMRC7kCjOMY)

In excel, select the cell next the first cell next to the first item on the right, then enter `=A1&","`